# How to use DWOLL's API in iphone application?

Tags: iphone, integration, sample, dwolla

I have created an application where there is online payment option for the users and for this i want to use DWOLLA's API.I am not able to find any reference for integrating DWOLLA's API.
Please suggest me any sample code for iphone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate DWOLLA's API in ios?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547180/how-to-integrate-dwollas-api-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

You can download Dwolla SDK from [here](https://github.com/Dwolla/dwolla-ios).

Comment: Read the notes and follow the steps

Comment: thanks for helping me.I followed all the steps but still i am finding it difficult to import those API classes in my project please guide me through this.

Comment: what difficulties ? please be specific or how could I help you ?

Comment: I have downloaded the API from the link you sent.And followed these steps:Add DwollaOAuth project as subproject to application
- Add DwollaOAuthLib as a target dependency in "Build Phases"
- Add libDwollaOAuthLib.a to "Link Binaries with Libraries" in "Build Phases"
- Add $(SRCROOT)/dwolla-ios/DwollaOAuthLib to "Header Search Paths" (select recursive)
For adding this dwolla project as a subproject i have draged and dropped it into my project.but from there i dont know how to do the further things.Please help me.